# Where can I ask a question about medical equipment?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

This question is really strange, because it is "absurdly" unusual. I need an answer to this:

> How do machines and for that matter the tools that doctors use measure TSH (thyroid) levels? What are the mechanisms? Are there sensors or any other special requirements, any special techniques per se?

I'm conflicted. Because this is a biology question (kind of), a medicine question (kind of), an electronics question (kind of)... I think you get my problem (hint: it's the kind of phrase). I can't find a site where all of these topics kind of fit in. Is there any site or is this something I might ask somewhere else. I tried searching on Google and I didn't find anything (admittingly my search wasn't that thorough, but I kept trying). So, I thought it'll be better if I asked this from a professional in the field. Where should I ask this?

Comment: (Note TSH isn't produced by the thyroid, but by the pituitary.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We have an [Engineering](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/) site in the network, and it takes questions about [biomedical engineering](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biomedical-engineering). I'd try that one, but please check their [Help Center](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before posting your question.

Comment: Thanks, I think that sites suits this well.

Comment: An old question (recently bot-bumped), but there's also [Medical Sciences](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/)